# When i select one in selection field pass all values in selection to function

Tags: angular

This is my code in an HTML file. I want to get only one value when I select among this selection filed values. The case is when I select the first option i.e. the empty value I need to pass all values to method onEnvNameSelected() function.

```
<label class="control-label">Select want environment: </label>
<select
  class="custom-select"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedEnvName"
  [disabled]="!disableCustName"
  (ngModelChange)="onEnvNameSelected($event)"
  (ngModelChange)="selectedEnvName = $event"
>
  <option value="" selected>Please select ...</option>
  <option *ngFor="let envNames of eName" value="{{ eName }}">
    {{ envNames }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please provide more details and clarity on your issue.

Comment: can't you use all items in the function when empty value is passed to the change event?  I guess eName has already all the items. Moreover, this naming convention is not recommendable. let envNames of eName is confusing.

Comment: check this if it helps: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-etyhx8?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: try <option value="{{eName}}" seleccted>Please select...</option>